# send the data in the request

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui

In this code I am trying to send the data to the request, and the data that is being sent is present and it prints it in the console, but my problem is in the "slice" file, as it does not take the data and print that it is not there

how can i solve my problem?

slice.js:

```
export const assignToUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "invoicesApp/invoice/assignToUser",
  async ({ id, userId, assignmentNote }, { dispatch }) => {
    console.log("hi in new function");
    console.log("invoiceId, userId, message", id, userId, assignmentNote);
    const response = await axios
      .post(`/invoices/flow/${id}/assign-to-user`, { userId, assignmentNote })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error response: ", error);
      });
    const data = await response.data.data;
    console.log("approve invoices: ", data);
    dispatch(getInvoices());
    return data;
  }
);

[assignToUser.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      console.log(" action.payload: ", action.payload);
      action.payload;
    },
```

called.js:

```
        <Button
              onClick={(ev) => {
                //here is print correct 
                console.log(
                  "I am inside function: ",
                  "id: ",
                  id?.id,
                  ",users id: ",
                  userId,
                  ",message:",
                  message
                );
               dispatch(assignToUser({ invoiceId, userId, assignmentNote }));
                // assignToUserToApproveInvoiceHandleClick(ev);
                handleAssignToUserDialogClose();
              }}
              style={{ color: "#212529", fontWeight: 500 }}
              color="primary"
              autoFocus
            >
              Assign to approve
            </Button>
```

this is the form of the response:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you add `{}` for the `userId` in `Slice.js` file

```
async (invoiceId, { userId, message }, { dispatch }) => {
```

Is that an object? Are you trying to destructure the object for `userId`?

Shouldn't it be something like the below?

```
async (invoiceId, userId, message, { dispatch }) => {
```

Check the basic example in [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#overview). Not sure how did you configure your redux. It would be really great if you share a reproducible example on the sandbox.

Comment: i try your answer but it doesn't work

Comment: i edit my post please check it

Comment: Can you share the values of `invoiceId`, `userId`, `message` in console log for this line ```async (invoiceId, userId, message, { dispatch }) => {```

Comment: the request it doesn't send, i don't know why

Comment: You put the console before making an API call. I think your console values should be printed.

Comment: i edit my post and may problem is now: status 400 Request URL: https://ite-ria.herokuapp.com/api/v1/invoices/flow/undefined/assign-to-user and invoiceId is undefined, Although I printed it in the console and it has value and this error {"statusCode":400,"code":400,"message":"Validation failed (numeric string is expected)"}

Comment: `async ({ id, userId, assignmentNote }, { dispatch })`... use `invoiceId` instead of `id`.